# When and why should I use void as the return type of a function in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm currently practising C and learning pointers and arrays. I watched a tutorial where the instructor changed the function from `int aFunction()` to `void aFunction()`. Of course, he didn't say why — that's why I'm here. So I'm wondering: when and why should someone use `void` as the return type for a function.

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to return a value.

Comment: It's the other way around. You use `void` by default. And if you want to `return` something, you use the type of the thing you're returning instead.

Comment: When the function does not return a value, for example exit() to exit the program.

Comment: `int aFunction()` is for a function that must return an int in all code paths of the function. If you write a function and you don't have anything to return or don't want to return a value use `void aFunction()`

Comment: What does your text-books say? What have your teacher said?

Comment: I don't think the `arrays` or `pointers` tags apply at all to the question.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I disagree that one should think of functions as returning void by default. That's a very imperative view of things.

Comment: Note that if the function doesn't take any arguments, you should also use `void` in the parameter list — `void aFunction(void)` — in both the declaration and definition of the function (but especially in the declaration).  If a function is declared `extern void aFunction();`, it means that nothing is known about the argument list except that it is not a function that takes a variable argument list (it isn't like `printf()`; it does not have a prototype that ends `, ...`).  It does NOT define a prototype for the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, you have to tell the compiler what are each of the types of the variables you declare. That is why you have things like `int` and `char*`.

And functions’ return values are no different. Compiler has to know what each of your functions return types are to work properly. Now if you have a function like `add(int a, int b)` typically you would want its return type to be of integer, that is why you would define it as

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Now consider you have a function that doesn’t return anything at all, now you need to tell your compiler that this function returns nothing. That is why `void` is used. You use `void` when the function does *something* but in the end doesn’t need to return any value to the program it was called from. Like this one:

```
void printAdd(int a, int b)
{
    printf(“a + b = %d”, a+b);
}
```

We are doing a bunch of stuff here but the result from the addition is not returned or stored but rather printed to the screen.

You can use the first function `add()` like this:

```
int abc = add(5, 7);
// abc is 12
```

while you can only use the second function like

```
printAdd(5, 7);
// you cannot store the value because nothing is returned.
// 5 + 7 = 12 is printed to the screen
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was well explained.

Answer (score 0):

The token(s) that precedes the function name in the function declaration is the type of the value that the function returns. In this case there is just one token, but type names may consist of multiple tokens. When you want to return an integer object, you can specify the return type to be `int`. When the function won't return anything, you use `void` return type.

Comment: The return type is not necessarily a single token and the token that precedes the function name is not necessarily a type: `FILE *fopen(const char *, const char *);`

Comment: Multiple kinds of tokens can be the last one before the function name; it could be `*` as in `void *foo(void)` or a structure tag as in `struct bar foo(void)` or a storage class specifier or a left parentheses or just part of the type name as in `long int foo(void)`. And a function with return type `int` does not return an integer object; it returns an `int` value (if it returns a value; the C standard does not require it to return anything; control may flow to the closing `}`).

Comment: Thank you so much, this was well explained.